# I can not delete session in Database Engine Tuning Advisor

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm currently using sql server 2008. I have a problem with DTA.
Here is my steps:

1. I created new session to analyze my query.
2. I canceled the process because it took so long to complete (1+ hour/query). On the time I had canceled, this process was on the 4th step (generating report).
3. I closed the session.
4. I tried to delete the session but DTA did not allow me to delete. it said it was aborting in status tool bar. I understood this sentence but I've waited to delete this session for 6 hours. i don't see why it is aborting so long. It is just one small query.

Anyone can help me on this?

Thank you.

**Edit: The solution is to kill the connection that is connecting to database first. That's it. Thank you.**

Comment: Thank Klaus. I found solution and updated already.

Comment: How to kill this connection? Which connection? Only DTA connection?

Comment: Kill the DTA process in Task Manager

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is trying to kill the connection that is connecting to database first. That's all.

Comment: How to kill connection and remove session in DTA ?

Comment: Kill the DTA process in Task Manager

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the current session(with aborting status) and open it then click preview the vorkload file and then click quit, after open again database tuning advisor and you[image] will be able to delete it.
please see the picture

Comment: I got this to work twice, but can't seem to get it to work consistently after trying every variation a few dozen times.

Answer (score 2):

Execute on the msdb-Database

```
exec dbo.sp_DTA_help_session --<-- get the session id
exec dbo.sp_DTA_delete_session 2 --<-- this is the session id
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me - the sessions were in finishing state - not stopped state - tuning end time had long past

Answer (score 0):

Change the time of your computer to greater than the Tuning Time Limit. You can see the limit on Tuning Options tab of the session. After changing the time, refresh the Session Monitor on the left pane until you see that the session is stopped. When stopped you can then delete the session. Don't forget to restore the correct time of your computer. :)